# How to execute and select statement within a select statement and do a string_agg or concat?

Tags: postgresql

I' trying to get an overview over a dozen tables within one select, including the data of the created select-stmt.

I already tried to do it with a sub-select , select execute(query) from table,
and a select of the select:

```sql
combinedTable looks like:
|schema_name  | table_name | column_name|
----------------------------------------
|schema1      | table1     | column1    |
|schema1      | table2     | column1    |
|schema1      | table3     | column1    |
|schema2      | table1     | column1    |
```

and I'm trying to get sth like

```sql
combinedTable looks like:
|schema_name  | table_name | column_name|executedSQL           |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|schema1      | table1     | column1    |value1, value2, value3|
|schema1      | table2     | column1    |value1, value2, value3|
|schema1      | table3     | column1    |value1, value2, value3|
|schema2      | table1     | column1    |value1, value2, value3|
```

and "value1, value2, value3" are all the result of the nested select

---

the table without the executed sql looks like:

```sql
|schema_name  | table_name | column_name|NotExecutedSQL                              |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|schema1      | table1     | column1    |select string_agg(myColumn, ', ') from schema.table group by someColumn;|
|schema1      | table2     | column1    |select string_agg(myColumn, ', ') from schema.table group by someColumn;|
|schema1      | table3     | column1    |select string_agg(myColumn, ', ') from schema.table group by someColumn;|
|schema2      | table1     | column1    |select string_agg(myColumn, ', ') from schema.table group by someColumn;|
```

The idea was to have a select statement like this

```sql
select execute t.a as foo 
from 
(
    select 
('select string_agg('||column_name||', '''||', '|| ''') from '||schema_name||'.'||table_name||' group by someColumn;') as a
from combined_table
) as t(a)
```

result of the sub-query is:

```sql
"select string_agg(myColumn, ', ') from schema.table group by someColumn;"
```

which in turn does give the expected result, but only for one table, I want the statement executed for all tables in the combined_table

```sql
-------
so expected/wished result would be:

|        foo         |
|--------------------|
|value1,value2,value3| <-- table1
|value1,value2       | <-- table2
|        ...         | <-- table ...
```

Comment: Please show us your input data and the whole expected output. To me, it is completely not clear what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: I hope this better understandable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should use a FOR LOOP over the columns of the table.  You can use RETURN QUERY to return one row per column.  Here's a basic function, which uses the table as an argument.  I'm using [regclass](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype-oid.html) here to avoid ambiguities between tables of the same name in different schemas.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION table_overview(tbl regclass)
  RETURNS TABLE (
    schema_name text,
    table_name  text,
    column_name text,
    vales       text
  ) AS $$
  DECLARE
    l_column_name text;
    l_schema_name text;
    l_table_name text;
  BEGIN
    -- Get the name of the schema and table from pg_class
    SELECT relnamespace::regnamespace::text, 
           relname::text INTO l_schema_name, l_table_name
      FROM pg_class
      WHERE oid = tbl;

    -- Loop over the columns
    FOR l_column_name IN 
      SELECT attname 
      FROM pg_attribute
      WHERE attisdropped = false
        AND attnum > 0
        AND attrelid = tbl
        ORDER BY attnum
    LOOP
      RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 
        FORMAT('SELECT %L, %L, %L, string_agg(%I::text, '','') FROM %s', 
           l_schema_name, l_table_name, l_column_name, l_column_name, tbl);

    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
  END;

$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Let's test it out:

```
CREATE TABLE public.test (a int, b int);
insert into test VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6);
CREATE TABLE public.test2 (c int, d int);
insert into test2 values (7, 8), (9, 10);
CREATE SCHEMA not_as_public;
CREATE TABLE not_as_public.test (e text);
INSERT INTO not_as_public.test VALUES ('a');


SELECT overview.* 
-- Use a values statement here to list the tables you want to query.  
FROM (VALUES ('test'::regclass), -- test is in public, already in our search_path, so we don't need to specify the schema
             ('test2'), -- same here
             ('not_as_public.test') -- this one is not in our search_path, so we specify the schema
     ) as v(tbl) 
CROSS JOIN LATERAL table_overview(tbl) as overview;
  schema_name  | table_name | column_name | vales
---------------+------------+-------------+-------
 public        | test       | a           | 1,3,5
 public        | test       | b           | 2,4,6
 public        | test2      | c           | 7,9
 public        | test2      | d           | 8,10
 not_as_public | test       | e           | a
(5 rows)


-- Alternatively, select the tables out of pg_class
SELECT overview.*
FROM pg_class
CROSS JOIN LATERAL table_overview(oid::regclass) as overview
WHERE relname like 'test%';
  schema_name  | table_name | column_name | vales
---------------+------------+-------------+-------
 public        | test       | a           | 1,3,5
 public        | test       | b           | 2,4,6
 not_as_public | test       | e           | a
 public        | test2      | c           | 7,9
 public        | test2      | d           | 8,10
(5 rows)
```

Comment: thanks :-)
I don't really understand how it works, but it does, so thanks very much

Comment: Feel free to ask specific questions, if you aren't sure how it works.  If it is working for you, though, it would be helpful to accept this answer so the question is properly tagged as answered.